# How to reference cell within '' worksheet title

Tags: excel, reference, cells, worksheet

I have the names of the tabs/worksheets (M-61,M-62,M-63W) at the top row (A1, B1, C1...etc)
I am trying to get a sum of several cells within the different sheets:

```
=SUM('M-60'!H21,'M-60'!H43,'M-60'!H86,'M-60'!H87,'M-60'!H97,'M-60'!H98)
```

However, right now I’m referring to the sheet itself, and have to apply the same formula to all the other sheets. This will require me to manually go and change all the sheet titles accordingly. 
I was wondering if there is any way to reference the top row with the sheet titles within the formula so it automatically refers to the row text instead of me having to manually change the sheet title.

*Edit*
Now i got the reference to work, just wondering how would I do a sum of several cells in that tab

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$F1&"'!H87",TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you mean like:  '\\[filepath]\[filename.xlsx]sheet1'!A1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H21"),INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H43"),INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H86:H87"),INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H97:H98"))
```

(though there may well be a much smarter way).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the INDIRECT function, which uses a string as an argument and converts it to a range. So

```
=M-60'!H21
```

is the same as

```
=INDIRECT("M-60'!H21")
```

or, if Sheet name is stored in, say, cell C1:

```
=INDIRECT(C1&"'!H21")
```

Your example has a SUM, though, which requires some adaptations. This your example:

```
=SUM('M-60'!H21,'M-60'!H43,'M-60'!H86,'M-60'!H87,'M-60'!H97,'M-60'!H98)
```

Since you are not using a range, you can convert that SUM into simple addition. Assuming Sheet name in cell C1

```
=INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H21")+INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H43")+INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H86")+INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H87")+INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H97")+INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H98")
```

This should solve your problem. More info [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx)

By the way, if you were using a range, the OFFSET function with INDIRECT as an argument would work. But that's not necessary here.

Comment: But insted of M-60, I want to be able to refer to cell C1 for instance which contains the text M-60. This way if I have several numbers i want to add, they all refer to the cell text so i can apply the same function for other tabs and refer to the top row.

Comment: In that case, use =INDIRECT(C1&"'!H21"). C1 will become "M-60", and the & will concatenate both strings.

Comment: Its giving me a #Ref error..I think its still refering to the current sheet and not the 'M-60' tab

Comment: @pnuts C1 has the the Tab names such as M-60, M-61 ..but i just got the formula to work..just wondering how do I use the sum function with this 
=INDIRECT("'"&F1&"'!H87",TRUE)
I want to be able to add several cells from the refered tab

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you were using it in a SUM. I'll edit my post to make it work with your case.

Comment: Indeed... Sorry, I'm new at this helping people online thing :) (I'm usually the go-to guy among coworkers, and working with Excel opened is much easier). By the way, the inverted commas are only necessary because of the '-' character in the sheet name. Without it, you could lose the `"'"&` part, which would make it more legible.

Comment: Did you check the last edit I made? It's `INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!H21")`. Again, sorry for the confusion...